# How to get the NUMBER of same characters from a paragraph using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to get the number of SAME letters from a pararaph using jQuery? so let's say I have this paragraph:

```
<div>like this printer</div>
```

I would like to get the number of characters for "i" meaning that I should get 3 since there are 3 "i"s. I was thinking about using $(div:contains(i)), but now sure how to implement this. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this demo:**

```js
var src = $('#src').text();

var count = (src.match(/i/g) || []).length;

$('#count').append(count);

alert(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="src">like this printer</div>
<p id="count"><strong>Count of "i" = </strong></p>
```

Comment: it woult be better to use method `.text()` instead of `.html()`. Your code will count also 'i' in `<div>`, `<li>` etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
//Your string
var str = "I like this printer";

//Shows the count of "i" in your string.
console.log(str.replace(/[^i]/g, "").length);
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

use .text().split()

```
$('div').text().split('i').length - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should understand [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Lastly, you can try this.

```
$("div:contains('i')").html().split('').reduce(function(p, n) {
   return n === 'i' ? ++p : p;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Well according to the jQuery API Documentation :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. Take a look at : https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ and you'll see that  quotation marks are not necessary...

Comment: However,  I like your answer so  I'm going to vote you up :)!. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method based on `String.match()` and `Array.length`:

```
function countSameCharsInElement(char,string){
    string.match(new RegExp(char, "g")) || []).length);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
countSameCharsInElement('i',$('div').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost all (all?) of the solutions proposed thus far will fail if the character being searched for is "special" to Regex's (for example, '.').
Here is a method which works regardless of the character being searched for (because it doesn't use a regex):

```
function countInstancesOf ( str, i ) {
    var count = 0;
    var pos = -1;

    while ((pos = str.indexOf(i, pos+1)) !== -1) ++count;
    return count;
}

var howmany = countInstancesOf( $('div').text(), 'i' );
```

Answer (score 0):

your answering own question. look up contains for strings in JavaScript. an easy to reference for a lot things web is w3 schools.
look there you will find your answer
 I recommend you do some more web searching before asking stack overflow.

Comment: This is not an answer. Try to post such things as a comment.